# How remote IP address entries in the xauth list, which belong to a marketing company affiliated with my router's ISP could appear

Tags: xorg, authentication

How and why these entries could appear in the output of xauth list (.Xauthority file):

```
92.242.132.16:1  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
92.242.132.16:2  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
92.242.132.16:3  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

I checked this IP address and it seems to belong to a BareFruit DNS, a marketing agency, which my ISP TalkTalk seems to prioritize.

I am clueless as to how these could make their way to such a critical file and what do they do?

Comment: Do you have SSH sessions active with X11 forwarded?

Comment: yes, 'X11Forwarding yes' in /etc/ssh/sshd_config. But the only time I ever ssh'd outside the local network was ssh.chat, but don't think that's related.